# Trying to get hash value for facebook set up for Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying t get the hash code to use for facebook.  After goggling I found [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1).

It seemed easy, install openssl and run the following command

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt`

The url it gace me to get Openssh is

http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list,
which is for windows, i cannot figure out how to get openssh for apple. i tried googling it, replacing the word windows in the url to apple and mac.  Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: openssh? or openssl? Note that Apple ships OS X with a version of openssl, in `/usr/bin/openssl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get a hash for facebook is to put this code in your app and it will print it for you:

```
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("my.package.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("hash key", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    }
```